# How to choose a group of columns in a Dask Dataframe?

Tags: python, dataframe, dask

Is there a way to choose a group of columns in a dask dataframe?

The slice `df [['col_1', 'col_2']]` does not seem to work.

Comment: "_does not seem to work_" - how exactly? Do you see an error message? If so, include it.

Comment: For me in dask `0.16.1` and pandas `0.22.0` it working nice.

Comment: It was my mistake. I passed to the slicing operator a list of strings in a numpy array receiving a "not implemented error", passing a python list instead it works correctly.

Comment: You might want to answer your own question with this answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was my mistake. I passed to the slicing operator a list of strings in a numpy array receiving a "not implemented error", passing a python list instead works correctly.